# Get rid of boost dependencies in TCP proxy. boost::system::error_code equivalent

Tags: c++, boost, dependencies, asio

I'm working on getting rid of the boost dependencies for [this](https://github.com/ArashPartow/proxy/blob/master/tcpproxy_server.cpp) TCP proxy server. I plan to use STANDALONE Asio. I have gotten rid of most of the dependencies moving everything to std C++11.

Here is the [link](https://gist.github.com/illera88/58eeb006aa48771c42077c28b18bb0fc) to my modified version

Nevertheless, there is still a couple things I don't know how do eliminate dependencies for:

- `boost::system::error_code` is one of them.
- `async_write` seems it is not getting the proper arguments with the modifications.

How can I translate those dependencies so it can compile without Boost?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Just had to change `boost::system::error_code` for `asio::error_code`